# Why we do not see beyond the cosmic horizon?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion, observable-universe

I've read that is because light hasn"t had time to reach us?
Would it someday reach us and would we be able to see beyond the horizon?

Comment: no - while we may speculate that light from stars beyond the cosmic horizon is indeed on the way towards us, it would take a longer-than-infinite amount of time to reach us :p

Comment: The radiation from near the cosmic horizon is really showing us things that were closer to us in the past than they are now. One can not get closer than "right here".

Answer (score 0):

We do see objects that are on the Hubble frame beyond the horizon, but we see them on the past light cone where they were not yet past the horizon. The cosmological horizon is at $r_h~=~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}$, with $\Lambda~\simeq~10^{-52}m^{-2}$ or about $14$ billion light years, which is where the redshift is $z~=~v/c$ $=~1$ This can be more precisely found with the Hubble law $v~=~Hd$ for $H~=~72km/sec-Mpc$. The CMB is however at $46$ billion light years away. Yet what we see are photons emitted far in the past before it had crossed the cosmological horizon relative to this local frame.

It is not possible to send a signal at any object that has $z~>~1$, which means it has since passed the horizon length. Similarly, an observer on such a distant galaxy could see the Milky Way in its early formation, but is not able now to ever send a signal to us.